# Quickly unify white background in illustrations with Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background-removal, white

Very often when I add illustrations to documents. I take pictures on a white background. The resulting image is good but not perfect.

On the following, you can clearly see the top right is almost white, but the bottom left is grayish.

My current quick&dity method is to adjust the level to make sure all borders are pure white. Then I can add my illustration without worrying about visible edges. However, this method is too brutal and the content gets saturated.

[image]

Ideally I would like an automatic filter (or a simple method) that removes the principal illumination component from the image. My current method is:

1. Select everything but the objects with the Magic Wand tool.
2. Invert the selection
3. Content fill with the background. I get the following:

[image]

4. Add a filter layer "Divide" with this background and I get this:

[image]

5. Slightly adjust the levels to make sure all the edges are pure white.

Is there a better, more professional method?

Comment: Can't you get more level into your right-hand strobe then pull it back a way so the falloff is less noticeable across your FoV?

Comment: Yes, I can do this, but this is just an example to emphasize the issue.

Comment: However I think that having a constant lighting would be a _more professional method_. Otherwise dealing with gradients will always require some manual touch

Comment: Not sure a fully automatic way is possible really, at least not with your sample image.  It will require manual retouching of some sort I think.  It would be much easier if the lighting on the photograph was completely consistent. The fall-off to the top left is what's making it harder than needs be. Fix your lighting setup.